# Rails precompile not creating directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have the following structure for app assets

```
 /app
     /assets
            /javascripts
            /images
            /stylesheets
            /fonts
```

When I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` all the assets are moved to

```
 /assets
```

Individual folders are not created. Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because of my reputation.

Compiled assets are written to the location specified in `config.assets.prefix`. By default, this is the /assets directory.

For more information check this out.
[Asset Pipeline - Precompiling Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)